# Counting line numbers in a text file

Tags: discord.js

Here is my code to check if there is 0 lines and then will say that there is 0 lines

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let file1 = fs.readFileSync('spotify.txt').toString();
    let file2 = fs.readFileSync('netflix.txt').toString();
    let file3 = fs.readFileSync('disney+.txt').toString();
    let lines1 = file1.split('\n');
    let lines2 = file2.split('\n');
    let lines3 = file3.split('\n');
    var lineCount1 = lines1.length;
    var lineCount2 = lines2.length;
    var lineCount3 = lines3.length;
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .addField(`This guild has the following service(s):`, `**SPOTIFY:**  ${lineCount1} \n **NETFLIX:** ${lineCount2} \n **DISNEY+:** ${lineCount3}`)
    message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
}
module.exports.help = { name: 'stock' }
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the total amount of linebreaks in a string you can use the following regex:

```js
(file1.match(/\n/g) || '').length;
```

Comment: The code returns a Number, so you'd have to replace your lineCount variables with it. For example: `var lineCount1 = (file1.match(/\n/g) || '').length; var lineCount2 = (file2.match(/\n/g) || '').length;` etc.

Comment: If i have 2 lines it says now 1 and 1 says 0

Comment: As I said it counts the number of linebreaks if you want to count the number of lines you just put `+1` after it

Comment: Hmm now if there is no lines it says 1

Comment: there isn't really such a thing as "no lines". An empty String is still a line.

Comment: Oh can you do it with text lines? For example: if there's no text it says 0

Comment: `var lineCount1 = !!file1 ? (file1.match(/\n/g) || '').length + 1: 0;` This will return the amount of Lines if the text contains a minimum of 1 characters, if it doesnt it will return 0

Comment: Thx for helping me ❤️